# sharepoint datetimecontrol takes default value as Today's date

Tags: datetime, sharepoint

sharepoint datetimecontrol takes default value as Today's date when its blank or empty
How can I set it to NULL, becuase each time it is kept blank it takes Today's date.
Also, I plan to do this without making any code changes in C#.
I wish to make only code changes to my aspx file & deploy, So that I need to require to build & re dploy the entire application.

Comment: Try asking this on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If not set, the SharePoint:DateTimeControl will return today's date. You need to test IsDateEmpty property instead.
/Pawel